# Remove single stand alone characters from string

Tags: php, regex

I have an example string below and would like to remove any characters which are single, so the following:

```
$string = 'N W N W Some useful test what I would like to keep'
```

can become: `$stringNew = 'Some useful test what I would like to keep'`

Also I would like a generic solution as the string above will vary and the stand alone letters in the string will vary as well. 
Any assistance in much appreciated.

Comment: and what's your effort to solve it?

Comment: Here's a hint, use "word boundries" `\b`.

Comment: Why isn't `I` being removed?

Comment: Actually you would get `Some useful test what would like to keep` because `I` is also a single character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `preg_replace()` to do this. Use the code below

```
<?php
$string = 'N W N W Some useful test what I would like to keep'
echo preg_replace('/\b\w\b\s?/', '', $string); // will print Some useful test what would like to keep
?>
```

And if you dont want I to be replaced then use this code

```
<?php 
$string = "N W N W Some useful test what I would like to keep";
$array = explode(" ",$string);
$new = "";
foreach($array as $p){
    if($p=="I"){
    echo " ".$p;
    }
    else{
        if(strlen($p)!==1){
            echo " ".$p;
        }
    }
}
echo trim($new); // will print Some useful test what I would like to keep
?>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: The `I` in the sentence is missing ^^

Comment: @Dwza I also come in single character so it will be definitely removed

Comment: I know... but op dont want this :)

Comment: @Dwza Now did what OP wanted.